# Sony Remote API with a7 iii getAvailableFNumber 40404

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Has anyone tried to run getAvailableFNumber through the Sony Remote API on the a7 iii?  I get a 40404 error, but it's not listed in their documentation.  I get the same error when running getAvailableShutterSpeed.  getAvailableIsoSpeedRate works, and all three of those methods work on the a6000.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you can do to possibly resolve this issue:

1. Try calling getEvent instead of getAvailableFNumber. getEvent will return a lot of useful information including the FNumber if available.
2. Try calling getAvailableApiList to see if getAvailableFNumber comes up as an endpoint you can call.

Unfortunately because all of the cameras that support the Camera Remote API are different there could be a few things causing the getAvailableFNumber endpoint to not be available. For instance your camera may need to be switched to shooting mode before this will work. Having a better idea of which camera you are using may help to solve the problem. Which of these supported cameras do you have?

- α7 *3
- α7R *3
- α7R II *3
- α7S *3

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/api-information/supported-features-and-compatible-cameras

Comment: its an a7 iii.  I actually have getEvent and getAvailableApiList checks prior to calling getAvailableFNumber, per the Sony documentation.  I ensure the camera is IDLE and that the api list returned getAvailableFNumber.